# Question about PHP template and controller files

Tags: php, templates, controller

First of all I apologise for this question in advance. I am in the very beginning of my PHP and SQL studies and feel hopelessly stuck. I had to create the following:

1. a simple web site with a landing page, a gallery page and a contact page
2. all should share a common masthead header and footer
3. each page needs to have a php controller file; and title, heading and other data needs to be set in variables.
4. there should be a master template for html output for every type of page that in turn will include the smaller page parts. (all data can be considered safe for this exercise, making filtering and escaping unnecessary)

Now what I have done so far is this:
index.php file containing:

```
**
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';

switch ($page) {
    case 'gallery':
        include 'galleryController.php';
        break;
    case 'form':
        include 'formController.php';
        break;
    default:
        include 'homeController.php';
        break;
    }
?>
<?php include 'template.php'; ?>**
```

then template.php file containing:

```
**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--header section-->
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

    <!--content section-->
    <?php include $content; ?>

    <!--footer section-->
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

</body>

</html>**
```

and for example footer:

```
**
<!--footer section-->
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="social-icon">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="Icons/facebook.png" alt="Studio Apartment Facebook account"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="Icons/instagram.png" alt="Studio Apartment Instagram account"></a>
    </div>

    <section class="newsletter-signup">
        <h3>Sign up for newsletter!</h3>
            <form class="newsletter-form" action="form.php" method="POST" id="theForm" autocomplete="on">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" id="email" required>
                <button type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">Sign up</button>
            </form>
    </section>
</footer>**
```

While what I did above works and I got passed with this assignment, it is still technically wrong and I want to fix it (more importantly understand what's wrong) in order to move on. I got a feedback that I need to set the footer in the template file as a variable, and the template file should be php with html in the variables ( such as $head" and "$title"). I am watching multiple tutorials and understand that to set a variable in the template file I would write something like this:

```
<footer><?php echo htmlspecialchars($footerVariable, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></footer>
```

and then set the footerVariable in the controller file?
BUT that is not having the template in php with html in variables. Also I am very confused in terms of how do I set the entire footer section in variable.
Anyway as you can see, I am making myself very confused about it all. Please help. :)

Comment: I don't see why the _whole_ footer content should be put into a variable here, can't see much sense in that. _"and the template file should be php with html in the variables ( such as $head" and "$title")"_ - can't tell what parts of the shown footer should be "dynamic" to begin with, so I would not know where in there you'd want to insert any variables.

Comment: For this pattern you are basically relying on a bunch of global variables such as `$title`. I would set some default values in `index.php` and then override them in your controllers. Also, `include $content;` is a little weird to me. Does each "controller" also specify an additional template to load? Can the controller take care of that automatically instead, and just set content that you can `echo` in your `index.php` file instead?